# IE Browser is halting during Jenkins run

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer

IE Browser is halting during Jenkins run.
Whereas its running fine when I run in my local machine.

**Halted at the below point:**
Only local connections are allowed
Feb 20, 2019 12:47:20 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

After this, its halted. The job is not running and even stopped. I have to manually stop the job.

The same test is executing fine for chrome browser from Jenkins.

I guess there are some setting needed in Jenkins slave machine. Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: What's your IE browser version? Please check your IE browser version and check the [Jenkins Browser Compatibility](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Browser+Compatibility+Matrix). Since this issue is related to Jenkins, I suggest you could post the problem to [Jenkins Issue forum](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed+IE+Browser+).

Comment: I have similar issue .. can anyone help? IE11 is installed on Slave machine